# How to show List of records after search request by jsp page

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am new to jsp and servlet.
I have to show list of records from database in **jsp** page after search against **variable number  parameters**. I have created listRecords method in servlet.
 please help

Comment: please post what have you tried till now.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list(ArrayList) of the record and pass it to the jsp page (either by request parameter or session).

Then use the jstl to display each element in the list
Here is a sample

```
<table>
  <c:forEach var="ele" items="${list}">
    <tr>
      <td>${ele.name}</td>
      <td>${ele.value}</td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```